# GROUP BY equivalent in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I'm dealing with a MongoDB collection that has about 3 million documents. These documents were converted from an SQL table. The structure is very simple:

```js
{
  RowId: 1234,
  UserId: 23,
  User: {
    UserName: "John"
  }
}
```

In SQL the query is very straightforward:

select max(RowId), UserId from SomeTable group by UserId

In the production server, this table has 3 million rows. This quite busy server returns 628 rows in less than 1 second. But in MongoDB, I just can't seem to find a way to return a similar response.

This is what I've tried:

```js
db.Events.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: "$UserId",
    lastRow: {
      $max: "$RowId"
    }
  }
}])
```

I've created indices in both RowId and UserId fields. But basically what happens is the Mongo process starts using more and more RAM and at some point, the GUI I'm using (Robo 3T) doesn't do anything. I have to kill the Mongo process.

Comment: You can make use of indexes with sort and match stage being first stages .You can transform query to include sort at the beginning and change your group to include last operator. Something like `db.Events.aggregate([{$sort:{RowId:1}},  { $group: {     _id: "$UserId",     lastRow: {       $last: "$RowId"     }   } }])`

Comment: @Veeram while using the index did help (.explain() says the winningPlan is using IXSCAN and not COLLSCAN), the response time for the query is awful. Under about 1M documents in the collection, it takes a couple of seconds. After that, it takes minutes to run. Just to be sure, I deleted the db folder and started over.